# Eclipse maven build path issue in case of custom sourceDirectory

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-eclipse-plugin

I have converted an existing Java project to a Maven project and Maven builds everything perfectly when using the command line.

When I import the same project into Eclipse and compile (by right-clicking the project -> runs as Maven build, it still compiles without any issue.

**However, I am not able to see the source folder. When I check the build path it gives warning - build path entry is missing.**

I am not using standard `src/main/java` since I had a pre-existing folder structure for the project which could not be changed.

Here's my pom (notice the **`sourceDirectory`** tag):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycom</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven</artifactId>
  <version>17.4</version>
  <name>maven</name>
  <properties>
    <projecrt.rootDir>../../java</projecrt.rootDir>
  </properties>
  <build>
    <finalName>re</finalName>
    <sourceDirectory>${projecrt.rootDir}</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>    
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>               
            <manifestEntries>
              <Build-Version>${buildversion}</Build-Version>
            </manifestEntries>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>  
</project>
```

and here's my directory structure:

```
Src/java
----maven/pom.xml
----com/mycom/<...> // application code
```

Comment: The way you are using the pom eclipse is unable to determine the source folders. You can either add the source folder through the UI manually (right-click -> Build-Path -> Use as source folder) or utilize the maven build helper plugin to add the source folder through maven in a way that eclipse recognizes the source folder correctly.

Comment: I strongly recommend to follow conventions ...

Answer (score 8):

You can use this [build-helper-maven-plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/index.html)

And configure it in your pom file this way

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sources>
                <source>some directory</source>
                ...
              </sources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

and now when you do `mvn eclipse:eclipse` the custom source folders will get added to the classpath entries in the `.project` file.
So, you wont need to do any manual configuration, your configuration will simply get build at run-time.
You can do the same for your test sources as well, if you have your tests in a custom source folder.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Please please never use `eclipse:eclipse` anymore. This will make m2eclipse useless, which is the best Maven Integration solution for Eclipse.

Comment: I am using the same maven plugin to add a generated source directory into the classpath, and I just need to do `Context menu` on the project → `Maven` → `Update project…` to make it work in Eclipse.

Comment: Is this solution about adding generated sources? My question is about being able to run/debug/edit the sources that would normally exist under `src/main/java` for standard maven directory structure. But in my case the directory structure is not standard. Will the above solution help in running / debugging / setting breakpoints on my source code in  the same way as it does when maven standards are used ( `src/main/java` )?

Comment: Yes it would, have you tried this yet ? And what challenges did you face ?

Comment: I tried but I didn't see the source folder yet. I will try again after cleaning my workspace.

Comment: The eclipse maven integration plugin internally uses `eclipse:eclipse` command. I dont think it does any harm if you do on your own. @RobertScholte

Answer (score 2):

Once your Java project is imported in the Eclipse workspace, you can [specify the actual src folder](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-OrganizingSources.htm):

Click Open Java perspective Window > Open Perspective > Other... > Java to change to the Java perspective.

- In Project layout group, change selection to Create separate source and output folders and edit Configure default... to modify Source folder name from "src" to "sources".

[image: https://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/gettingStarted/images/qs-OrganizeSources2.png]

In the settings of your project (`project => property => java build path`), you can also change/add src folders:

[image: https://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/gettingStarted/images/qs-OrganizeSources3.png]

Comment: it works, but you will have to repeat that configuration each time you change the maven project and regenerate the eclipse project. It is easyer with the build-helper-maven-plugin.